# Spring Boot Test: execute different sql scripts in tests depending on the active profile?

Tags: java, sql, spring, spring-boot

Is it possible with Spring Boot Test to set a conditional execution of sql scripts depending on the active profile?
I mean, I have my integration tests for repositories annotated with some `@sql` annotations like:

```
@Sql(scripts = "/scripts/entity_test_clear.sql", 
     executionPhase = Sql.ExecutionPhase.AFTER_TEST_METHOD)
```

- For a profile `h2` I want to execute **entity_test_clear.sql**
- For a profile `mysql` I want to execute **entity_test_clear_mysql.sql**

The reason for it is that I use different syntax for these databases, particularly this one:

- `ALTER TABLE organisation ALTER COLUMN org_id RESTART WITH 1;`
- `ALTER TABLE organisation AUTO_INCREMENT = 1;`

`Mysql` doesn't understand the syntax **#1**, while `h2` doesn't understand the syntax **#2** (despite the `mysql` mode set, like `MODE=MYSQL`)

By default, I use `h2` for IT tests, but also, in some rarer cases, I would like to check everything works smoothly with `Mysql` too.

P.S I could of course try a straight-forward solution with `@Profile` and hard code two copies of each test for `h2` and `Mysql`, but it is coupled with huge code duplication in tests, which I would like to avoid.

**EDITED:**

The test case looks like this:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@DataJpaTest
@AutoConfigureTestDatabase(replace= AutoConfigureTestDatabase.Replace.NONE)
public class EntityRepositoryTestIT {

    @Autowired
    private EntityRepository entityRepository;

@Test
@Sql(scripts = {"/scripts/entity_test_data.sql", "/scripts/entity_test_data_many.sql"}, 
     executionPhase = Sql.ExecutionPhase.BEFORE_TEST_METHOD)
@Sql(scripts = "/scripts/entity_test_clear.sql", 
     executionPhase = Sql.ExecutionPhase.AFTER_TEST_METHOD)
public void findTest() {
    Page<Entity> e = entityRepository.findBySomeDetails(1L, PageRequest.of(0, 20));
    Assert.assertEquals(3, e.getContent().size());
    Assert.assertEquals(1, e.getContent().get(0).getResources().size());
// more asserts

}
```

Thank you for any suggestions!

Comment: Can you show us how you make the test for one of h2 or MySQL

Comment: Added the test case

Comment: Why don't you use @Profile with separated classes putting the common logic in an another class?

Comment: OK, that seem to be one solution!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After some deeper digging into the issue I ended up with this simple workaround.

```
@Sql(scripts = "/scripts/entity_test_clear.sql", 
     executionPhase = Sql.ExecutionPhase.AFTER_TEST_METHOD)
```

For the `scripts` parameter, it is required to be a compile time constant. You cannot simply fetch a current profile value from the `application.properties` file and substitute it to run the right script name.

Introducing `@After` and `@Before` methods with `ScriptUtils` executing the right scripts is rather verbose and, in fact, didn't work for me (some freezing during script executing process occurred).

So what I did was just introducing a class with a single constant:

```
/**
 * Constant holder for exceptionally database IT testing purposes
 * for switching between h2 and mysql
 */
public class ActiveProfile {
    /**
     * Current profile for database IT tests.
     * Make sure the value is equal to the value of
     * <i>spring.profiles.active</i> property from test application.properties
     */
    public static final String NOW = "h2";
}
```

Then the @sql line becomes:

```
@Sql(scripts = "/scripts/test_data_clear_"+ ActiveProfile.NOW+".sql", 
     executionPhase = Sql.ExecutionPhase.AFTER_TEST_METHOD)
```

To use another database for testing (mysql) I just need to

1. change the current `spring.profiles.active=mysql` profile in the `application.properties` file
2. change this constant to `mysql`;

That doesn't mean to be the exemplary solution, just a workaround that simply works.

Answer (score 4):

You could use `@Profile` annotation with separated classes, each for every DMBS, putting the common logic in an another class to avoid the code duplication. You are using Spring so you could get it with something as below.

```
@Profile("mysql")
@Sql(scripts="... my mysql scripts...")
public class MySqlTests{
    
    @Autowired
    private CommonTestsLogic commonLogic;
    
    @Test
    public void mySqlTest1(){
       commonlogic.test1();
    }

}

@Profile("oracle")
@Sql(scripts="... my oracle scripts...")
public class MyOracleTests{
   
   @Autowired
   private CommonTestsLogic commonLogic;
   
   @Test
   public void myOracleTest1(){
       commonlogic.test1();
   }

}
```

Comment: I think this is quite laborious approach as I have hundreds of IT tests to rewrite like this, and furthermore such the tests look weird